# make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor for public fragment with class name and empty constructor

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, runtimeexception

I've just got a crash report from one of the users with the following error trace :

```
Unable to instantiate fragment packageName.Wizard$WizardFirstPage: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Here are the classes declarations :

`public class Wizard extends Other`

`public abstract class Other extends BaseActivity`

`public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

All classes are public, named and doesn't have user defined constructor.

As for the fragment `WizardFirstPage` : (defined in `Wizard`)

`public class WizardFirstPage extends Fragment`

No user defined constructor either.

What am I missing ?

Comment: add the static keyword. `public static class  WizardFirstPage extends Fragment`, fix all your compile time errors and run it again

Comment: @Blackbelt , should all inner fragments be static ? (it's runtime error BTW)

Comment: yes they have to be declared as static

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class WizardFirstPage extends Fragment
```

That is an inner class of `packageName.Wizard`. That will only work if the class is declared as `static`, as indicated by Blackbelt:

```
public static class WizardFirstPage extends Fragment
```

When the `Wizard` activity undergoes a configuration change, or is re-created after process termination, Android is going to try to create an instance of `Wizard$WizardFirstPage`. With your current approach, Android cannot do this, as only instances of `Wizard` can create instances of `Wizard$WizardFirstPage`. Changing `WizardFirstPage` to be `static` will fix this.

Comment: Pretty neat explanation. For me this inner class is an Adapter calling another Fragment to load in ViewPager. Let's see if that works!